# Add SCSS support to Vue project

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, webpack, sass

In my `packages.json` file by default I get:

```
"postcss": {
"plugins": {
  "autoprefixer": {}
}}
```

When I add `<style lang='scss'>` It doesn't compile like magic like it does for Typescript support. I know I will need to specify some NPM package as devDependencies and specify something above in the `postcss` section to get scss to compile, but I can't find any documentation outside of webpack so I am lost.

Comment: if you create the project with vue-cli3, it's one of the options.  It works out of the box when you choose it.  No add'l config work needed.

Answer (score 0):

See https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html.

> For example, to compile our `<style>` tag with SASS/SCSS:
>
> ```
> npm install -D sass-loader node-sass
> ```
>
> In your webpack config:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   module: {
>     rules: [
>       // ... other rules omitted
>
>       // this will apply to both plain `.scss` files
>       // AND `<style lang="scss">` blocks in `.vue` files
>       {
>         test: /\.scss$/,
>         use: [
>           'vue-style-loader',
>           'css-loader',
>           'sass-loader'
>         ]
>       }
>     ]
>   },
>   // plugin omitted
> }
> ```
>
> Now in addition to being able to `import 'style.scss'`, we can use SCSS
>   in Vue components as well:
>
> ```
> <style lang="scss"> /* write SCSS here */ </style>
> ```
>
> Any content inside the block will be processed by webpack as if it's
>   inside a `*.scss` file.

Comment: Perhaps I am naive but I was hoping I could do this without webpack. I figured since I can compile Typescript in Vue files without webpack I could do same with SCSS. Maybe I am misunderstanding and my packages.json TypeScript configuration is using webpack somehow.

Comment: I don't have a `webpack.config`, only `vue.config.js`; I understand that the `webpack.config.js` is generated at runtime. How do I add the config?

Comment: This answer causes a build error: `Error: No loader specified`